# Search List item is not working in SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, search, search-scope

I have created 2 list  columns inside a SharePoint list and entered some data also. Crawled properties were created automatically so I have created managed property and mapped it to those automatically created crawled properties.

Managed properties are set to Searchable and Queryable and CRawled properties are set to "Include in full-text index" .

Search is working if I search from list search but when I search from Search vertical (Search this site) from the top left drop down, it returns no result.

Can someone please help me to include column value in "Search this site" search ?

Answer (score 1):

SharePoint Online targets between 15 minutes and an hour for the time between upload and availability in search results (also known as index freshness). In cases of heavy environment use, this time can increase to six hours.

http://www.sharepointnutsandbolts.com/2013/10/waiting-for-search-crawl-in-office-365.html

You could also manually request crawling like this:

1. On the site, go to the list or library that you want to re-index.
2. In the ribbon, click the Library tab or the List tab.
3. In the Library ribbon, choose Library Settings. Or, in the List ribbon, choose List Settings.
4. On the Settings page, under General Settings, choose Advanced settings.
5. Scroll down to Reindex Document Library or Reindex List, and click the button. The content will be re-indexed during the next scheduled crawl.

[Manually request crawling and re-indexing of a site, a library or a list](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/crawl-site-content)

Comment: Performed re-indexing multiple times and it's been 4-5 days but still I can't search using item value by querying "Search this site" vertical. Although, I can search it using "Everything" vertical.

Answer (score 0):

In SharePoint online search management we often have to wait for the crawl timer job to kick in, sometimes requesting a reindex of the list speeds that up.
How long ago did you change the managed property?

Comment: I did that on Thursday and still I can't search the column value from "This site" vertical.

Comment: How about from the generic search site? (unlikely but just to be sure)

Comment: It's searchable from search site. Earlier from there also it was not searchable but today suddenly it became searchable.